# How to extract Graph Button wrappers / annotations?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

```
graph= Graph[{Button[1->2, Echo["click"];]}];

InputForm @ graph
```

> ```
> Graph[
>   {1, 2}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2]}, 
>   { AnnotationRules -> {
>       DirectedEdge[1, 2] -> {Button -> Unevaluated[Echo["click"]; ]}
>     }
>   }
>   ]
> ```

```
AnnotationValue[graph, AnnotationRules]
```

> >>click 
> {1 -> 2 -> {Button -> Null}}

I am not sure why developers chose to use `Unevaluated` instead of `ButtonFunction`.

Regardless, is there an idiomatic way to extract that button annotation / wrapper?

Comment: `AnnotationValue[{graph, 1 -> 2}, Button]` gives `Unevaluated[Echo["click"];]`, so for all of them: `AnnotationValue[{graph, #}, Button] & /@ EdgeList[graph]`?